# Will a magnet diffuse/defocus a laser?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, laser

I have read through hundreds of questions here and we discuss why light is not bent by an electric or magnetic field (at least not at easily visible levels in the classical sense), but that there is phenomena like Faraday effect.

But if a light (EM wave) can interact with charged particles, shouldn't the converse be true? That charged particles affect light? Is there a practical example of this?

Also, a magnetic field won't bend light, but will it diffuse a laser beam?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, is refraction not the bending of light due to the electric field, rather than the mass density?